# How To Section Data Based On Custom Date Parameters

Tags: swift, model, uicollectionview, structure, sections

I'd like to section my model based on date parameters;

The sections should be;

1. Today
2. Yesterday
3. This Week
4. Last Week
5. This Month
6. Last Month
7. This Year
8. Last Year
9. Older

I have a custom section model;

```
struct NotificationSection {
    var date: Date
    var notifications: [NotificationViewModel]
}

private var sections = [NotificationSection]()
```

I am currently sectioning as;

```
private func firstDayOfMonth(date: Date) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .month], from: date)
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }

private func sectionData() {
        let groups = Dictionary(grouping: self.notifications) { (notification) in
            return firstDayOfMonth(date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: notification.createdAt))
        }
        self.sections = groups.map { (key, values) in
            return NotificationSection.init(date: key, notifications: values)
        }
        self.sections.sort { (lhs, rhs) in lhs.date > rhs.date }
    }
```

But I'm not sure how I would structure the sections like this. Would I run an extension on Date?

### UPDATE

I use this function to section data based on TimeInterval rather than date.

```
func getDay(from interval: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
        let calender = Calendar.current
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
        if calender.isDateInToday(date) { return 0 }
        else if calender.isDateInYesterday(date) { return 1 }
        return 2
    }
```

Comment: Your sections would have duplicate data. For instance, today would also appear in this week, this month and this year. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No sorry, If the object is today it will be in today section if yesterday yesterday and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Might not be the cleanest approach but works for now.

```
func sectionData() {
    let groups = Dictionary(grouping: self.notifications) { (notification) in
        return getDay(from: notification.createdAt)
    }
    self.sections = groups.map { (key, values) in
        return NotificationSection.init(date: key, notifications: values)
    }
    self.sections.sort { (lhs, rhs) in lhs.date < rhs.date }
}

func getDay(from interval: TimeInterval) -> TimeInterval {
    let calender = Calendar.current
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    if calender.isDateInToday(date) { return 0 }
    else if calender.isDateInYesterday(date) { return 1 }
    return 2
}

func getSectionTitle(from interval: TimeInterval) -> String {
    if interval == 0 { return "Today" }
    else if interval == 1 { return "Yesterday" }
    return "Older"
}
```

1. Section data based on time interval not date.
2. Get the day from the time interval.
3. Convert the time interval to string for section title.